# AWS VPC: IPSEC VPN: Change the preshare -- how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Have read 50 pages of docs, and googled, and what is the answer?

When you create a vpn in the VPC control panel, AWS generates the preshare.

Fine.

So after the consultant has the configuration done, and we want to change the preshare, what / how do we do it?

Answer (score 1):

The following documentation explains that you need to delete/recreate the VPN connection. You don't need to delete the VPC or the virtual private gateway.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html#CompromisedCredentials

There is no way to simply change the PSK and nothing else.